# SQL Server clustered columnstore index insert

Tags: sql-server, clustered-index, columnstore

I'm using SQL Server 2017. I want to use clustered columnstore index (CCI) rowgroup elimination by column YearID. Previously I was building clustered rowstore index on YearID and building CCI with MAXDOP=1 on top of it, but it started timeouting. What other options do I have? Now I rewrote my script by creating  CCI from the beginning and changing my query into a series of inserts like this:

```
INSERT INTO CCITable()
SELECT YearID, otherColums
FROM ...
WHERE YearID = 1

INSERT INTO CCITable()
SELECT YearID, otherColums
FROM ...
WHERE YearID = 2
...
INSERT INTO CCITable()
SELECT YearID, otherColums
FROM ...
WHERE YearID = N
```

Also I noticed, that 1 iteration using INSERT INTO CCITable()WITH(TABLOCK) performs faster, but a bunch of them performs slower. This script is the only query using CCITable. Any ideas why?

Comment: To my knowledge, there isn't any other way of guaranteeing the insert order into a columnstore index. Hopefully Microsoft implement this soon! The only other method is to start using partitioning, so that you can force a very rough order over the data. That should in theory then allow you to rebuild individual partitions using your existing method